# React Native json object does not show in ListView

Tags: json, listview, react-native

I'm new to RN and am trying to show a ListView populated with data from a json array, If I use a simple array then I can see the data however when I use the json array as shown in the code I don't see anything populated when I run the emulator. Is there a specific way to handle the json in my example below to show it in the ListView:

```
class FetchExample extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // Initialize the hardcoded test data - to be replaced by JOSN fetch
    let data = {"Vehicles":[[
      {"vehicle_make": "Toyota", 
      "vehicle_model": "Camry", 
      "vehicle_year": "2015", 
      "vehicle_price_range": "$$ (10-30)", 
      "car_id": 1127, 
      "vehicle_color": "Black", 
      "vehicle_car_accidents": "No", 
      "vehicle_no_owners": "1", 
      "car_vehicle_location": "Lot", 
      "vehicle_city_location": "L.A", 
      "vehicle_mileage": 10864, 
      "vehicle_vin": 1234, 
      "vehicle_off_lease": "Yes", 
      "vehicle_state": "CA"
    }]]};
    const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.state = {
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(data)
    };
    console.log(data);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{paddingTop: 22}}>
        <ListView
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={(rowData) => <Text>{rowData.Vehicles}</Text>}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If I refer to [the docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html), It looks like your `data` should be an array rather than an object. can you try with the following?

```
let data = [
  {"vehicle_make": "Toyota", 
  "vehicle_model": "Camry", 
  "vehicle_year": "2015", 
  "vehicle_price_range": "$$ (10-30)", 
  "car_id": 1127, 
  "vehicle_color": "Black", 
  "vehicle_car_accidents": "No", 
  "vehicle_no_owners": "1", 
  "car_vehicle_location": "Lot", 
  "vehicle_city_location": "L.A", 
  "vehicle_mileage": 10864, 
  "vehicle_vin": 1234, 
  "vehicle_off_lease": "Yes", 
  "vehicle_state": "CA"
}];
```

edit: 
you can instead replace

```
dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(data)
```

with

```
dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(data.Vehicles[0])
```

but I'd suggest you flatten your data as much as you can.

edit 2:
The render method also needs modification. try to change `renderRow` to the following:

```
renderRow={(rowData) => <Text>{rowData.vehicle_make}</Text>}
```

Comment: Thanks, I've tried your suggestion however I still do not see any ListView components output to the screen. I can do a console.log(data.Vehicles) and see that data is there.

Comment: I think I got it - now the data passed to `cloneWithRows` is an array, you have to render it properly. Try with the following: `renderRow={(rowData) => <Text>{rowData. vehicle_make + ' ' + rowData. vehicle_model}</Text>}`

Comment: also, is your goal to display all the properties in the JSON object? if so, let me know and I will update my answer - you'd have to have all those properties in an array rather than properties of an object.

Comment: Thanks again vgrafe with the help. I am trying to display the properties in the JSON object, there will be multiple vehicles returned in the JSON, I oly have one in the example. Adding the rowData.vehicle_model does work, I then added the renderRow function to show a number of the properties in the <text> tag, however when I add a second vehicle dataset to the JSON I get the following error: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Object.keys(dataBlob[sectionID])') I think you're right in that I have to change the JSON object to an array, any idea how to do that? Again appreciate your help.

Comment: It looks like you did not grasp JSON yet; you should get your head around how to use it properly first. For example, build up your JSON array with as a n array of strings, then put objects in it and map to their properties in the view, etc.